# Golang How to Unmarshal JSON with unquoted fields?

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

My JSON fields in a `[]byte` slice don't have quotes. How to customize Golang's `json.Unmarshal` or pre-format the data to add the necessary double-quotes?

Example ([Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/D-9VoTIdz8A)):

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    // Success:
    // blob := []byte(`{"license_type": "perpetual","is_trial": false}`)
    // Fails:
    blob := []byte(`{license_type: "perpetual",is_trial: false}`)

    type License struct {
        LicenseType string `json:"license_type,omitempty"`
        IsTrial bool `json:"is_trial,omitempty"`
    }
    var license License
    if err := json.Unmarshal(blob, &license); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error:", err)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("%+v", license)
    }
}

error: invalid character 'l' looking for beginning of object key string
```

This data is part of an API response, so any post-processing should be done without knowledge of the structure.

Comment: JSON without double qouted keys it's not JSON at all.

Comment: `An object structure is represented as a pair of curly brackets surrounding zero or more name/value pairs (or members).  A name is a string`  [link](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159#section-4)

Comment: You can look into packages that can still parse this. One of them is [this one](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/ohler55/ojg/sen), but it [doesn't seem](https://play.golang.org/p/ZdURM5SC8cb) like it considers struct tags. I wrote [a function](https://github.com/xarantolus/jsonextract/blob/abbf1b03802fc6f83921d77164e59be616aac60a/reader.go#L271-L466) some time ago that transforms JavaScript notation objects to JSON that can then be decoded using the stdlib `encoding/json`, maybe that's something you could use

Comment: You may have success with a YAML parser, since it's a superset of JSON and quotes are optional.

Answer (score 6):

**Solution**

Parse non-standard json with yaml, which is a superset of json. Works.

Shout-out to [@Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/603316/peter) for the solution via comment above:

> You may have success with a YAML parser, since it's a superset of JSON and quotes are optional.

[Working Code](https://play.golang.org/p/AMvxeiJ0E3x)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

func main() {
    blob := []byte(`{license_type: "perpetual",is_trial: true}`)
    type License struct {
        LicenseType string `yaml:"license_type,omitempty"`
        IsTrial bool `yaml:"is_trial,omitempty"`
    }
    var license License
    if err := yaml.Unmarshal(blob, &license); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error:", err)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("%+v", license)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is so interesting that the yaml library is more robust than the json library, but I'll be darned if this doesn't work perfectly. Thank you kind stranger.

Comment: I was trying this approach and one problem which may not be immediately obvious is that it doesn't preserve the order of keys/fields.